# Replace substring in a column of multiple entries per row using values of another dataframe column joined by shared column

Tags: r, regex, string, dataframe

I have 2 `data. Frame`s in **r**:

1. `df1` contains data I want to modify, (can have multiple entries per row)
2. `df2` contains data to modify `df1`, (single values per row)

I can join using `df1$ID` and `df2$Entry`.

**I want to:**

1. **Modify `df1$column1`** (this column can have multiple entries per row separated by `;`):

- To replace the substrings of all alphanumeric characters, including colons (`:`) and forward-slashes (`/`),
- But not replacing the values in parentheses (`(`, `)`) including the parentheses themselves, for each element in the string separated by semi-colon (`;`),
- Using replacement values in `df2$column3`,
- e.g. replace all the `column1` "alphanumeric*" with `column3` "Alt_alphanumeric*".

2. **Modify `df1$column2`** (this column can have multiple entries per row separated by `;` ):

- To replace the substrings of all alphanumeric characters, including colons (`:`) and forward-slashes (`/`),
- for each element in the string separated by semi-colon and space (`;` ),
- Using replacement values in `df2$column3`,
- e.g. replace all the `column2` "alphanumeric*" with `column3` "Alt_alphanumeric*".

The difficulty is that the separated strings in `column1` and `column2` don't match the text  in `column3`.

I did initially try to match using some combination of `strsplit(as.character(df1$column2), '; ')` and `pattern <- "(?<=\\()(.*?)([[:alnum:]]+)(.*?)(?=\\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([[:alnum:]]+)"` with a fourth column: `df2$column4` which did contain the same text, but the replacement did not occur for all rows. I think a join method is more robust, and I would prefer it. *For brevity that attempt has not not been included, but the failed attempt can be if required*.

```r
# Example
df1 <- data.frame(
 ID = (c"A", "B"), 
 column1 = c("alphanumeric1(VALUE1);alphanumeric2(VALUE2)", "alphanumeric3(VALUE3)"),
 column2 = c("alphanumeric1; alphanumeric2", "alphanumeric3"), 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df2 <- data.frame(
 Entry = c("A", "B", "C"), 
 column3 = c("Alt_alphanumeric1", "Alt_alphanumeric2", "Alt_alphanumeric3"), 
 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: if you add your desired output it becomes easier to answer to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified the setup, as in principle if its solved for reconstructing column1 based on column3, you can apply similar logic to fix column2 so lets focus on column1 ;
would this approach work ?

```
library(tidyverse)
# Example
df1 <- data.frame(
  ID = c("A", "B"), 
  column1 = c("alphanumeric1(VALUE1);alphanumeric2(VALUE2)", "alphanumeric3(VALUE3)"),
  #column2 = c("alphanumeric1; alphanumeric2", "alphanumeric3"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  Entry = c("A", "B", "C"), 
  column3 = c("Alt_alphanumeric1", "Alt_alphanumeric2", "Alt_alphanumeric3"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

df_3 <- left_join(
  df1,
  df2,
  by=c("ID"="Entry")
) |> rowwise() |> mutate(
  col1_vals = list(str_split_1(column1,";")),
  col1_keep = list(unlist(str_extract_all(col1_vals,"\\(.*?\\)"))),
  col1_reinsert = list(paste0(column3,col1_keep)),
  col1_recomb = paste0(col1_reinsert,collapse = ";")
)
```

Here I kept interim columns so you can see / understand the workings;
obviously this can be reduced to either be inlined; or simply not selected out.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. This methodical approach was really useful for me. As it turned out I actually couldn't merge on that shared column due to the columns of the data in `df2` (so my question was a little off). Instead I used: `df1 %>% str_split() %>% unnest() %>% mutate(new_ID = str_replace_all())` to create the column `new_ID`. Next `df2 %>% filter(Entry %in% df1$new_ID)` to get rows that match. Lastly, `df1 %>% left_join(df2, by="new_ID" = "Entry") %>% group_by(df1_unique_key) %>% summarise(new_col1 = paste(column3, collapse = "; "))`.